Suppress "Edge rulez" popup in Windows through registry or Powershell?
How can I suppress this window from coming up whenever a new user logs into Windows?

Browse the web with the best performing browser on Windows
Microsoft Edge is the only browser optimized for Windows and comes
with built-in features that can help you save time, money, battery,
and more whenever you browse.  It will also vacuum your car.
edge_annoy

Web search results indicate I just need to update to the latest version of Edge or install the latest Windows Updates and it will go away.  I have done so, both of which now say no more updates available, but the window persists for all new users.  I'm unsure if the difference in my case might be that these hosts were imaged using Windows Enterprise N.  Version is 22H2 build 19045.4780
The reason this is causing problems is that I have a series of hosts that feed a proprietary app UI through the RemoteApp feature of Azure Virtual Desktop.  After some recent updates, newly deployed hosts have also started feeding this Edge annoy screen to users along with the app, through RemoteApp.  Users never launch the Windows shell on these hosts, just the RemoteApp stream.  Besides being in the way and confusing for users who don't understand the pop-up is coming through the app stream, I don't want users opening Edge on the remote host, which this popup prompts them to do.
Ideally I can just add a registry entry (or some Powershell command) upon host deployment to turn it off, but if I have to make a change to the image the hosts are created from and redeploy them all, I can do that too.  Some 'disableRidiculousAnnoyance=1' registry key would be the best, I just haven't been able to find info about one online.  TIA for any suggestions.

Try:
cmd ->
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge" /v HideFirstRunExperience /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

This did the trick thank you.  In my case I added the following to the Powershell that runs on deployment
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft" -Name "Edge" -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge" -Name "HideFirstRunExperience" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force

@OKreboots glad I've been able to help!
